# Не получается совершить вход в вк через API, ругается интерпретатор

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Все делаю по мануалу: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vk/1.5

собсна вот код: [image]

Объясните плиз, почему ругается

Comment: В сообщении об ошибке говорится, что для вызова функции требуется два аргумента, а задан только один аргумент.

Comment: Не используйте картинки, чтобы текст ошибки показать. Это мешает найти этот сообщение людям с тем же вопросом. Если не знаете как скопировать текст из консоли, то задайте отдельный вопрос специально об этом.

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете старую версию инструкции. Новая находится здесь https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vk/2.0.2 и здесь http://vk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#vk-session

```
session = vk.Session(access_token='############')
vkapi = vk.API(session)
```